# Can cluster chains end with 0 or 1?

Tags: fat32

In the course of my research into making a formal model for FAT32, I've come across an implementation detail that's making my work really complicated: what values are allowed to occur at the end of a cluster chain?

According to [Microsoft's specification](https://staff.washington.edu/dittrich/misc/fatgen103.pdf), "The list of free clusters in the FAT is nothing more than the list of all clusters that contain the value 0
in their FAT cluster entry.", a corollary of which is that 0 cannot be the value at the end of a clusterchain, only EOC can be there. However, [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#Cluster_values) "Otherwise, if this value occurs in cluster chains (e.g., in directory entries of zero length or deleted files), file system implementations should treat this like an end-of-chain marker." for 0, citing this claim to an obscure German-language book.

So I really wanted to ask folks who work with filesystems whether they consider 0 (and 1) to be valid end-of-clusterchain markers in implementations.

Update: I checked the Linux kernel implementation of FAT32 and the [function for counting free clusters](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.5/source/fs/fat/fatent.c#L649) seems to count all zeros as free clusters, no more and no less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A further examination of the Linux FAT32 code showed that clusterchains which end with 0 are [considered invalid clusterchains](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.5/source/fs/fat/file.c#L327) and cause a return value of -EIO.